# Wikipedia Dump will become huge in Lucene?

Tags: java, xml, lucene, wikipedia

Indexing Wikipedia Dump, which is a 35GB XML file, turns out to be huge in Lucene (see code below for an overview). After 100 articles, with fields not stored, i have ~35 MB indexing space used, which means for ~3.5 million articles, i use over 1.2 TB! How is this possible, given that the original file is only a tiny fraction of that size. Is this package that inefficient or is Lucene just having really large index storage needs? Am I overlooking something?

I could only explain it if I assume that the first 100 articles from Wikipedia are unnaturally large and do not represent very much a normal article, in which case I would massively overestimating it. Can somebody tell me some numbers of how big their dump (indexed with Lucene) turned out and how long it took?

Here the code:

```
            package example;

            import edu.jhu.nlp.wikipedia.*;
            import edu.jhu.nlp.language.Language;

            import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
            import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
            import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
            import org.apache.lucene.document.*;
            import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
            import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
            import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
            import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
            import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
            import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

            import java.io.File;
            import java.io.FileInputStream;
            import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.util.Date;
            import java.util.Vector;

            public class WikipediaTextFacetIndexer {

                protected String facetName = null;
                protected ConfigurationManager configManager = null;
                protected String contentFolder = null;
                protected String indexFolder = null;
                private static int counter = 0;

                public void index() {

                    // true creates a new index / false updates the existing index
                    boolean create = false;

                    // check if data directory exists
                    logger.debug("wikipedia dump file = " + contentFolder);
                    final File wikipediaDumpFile = new File(contentFolder);
                    if (!wikipediaDumpFile.exists() || !wikipediaDumpFile.canRead()) {
                        logger.error("Wikipedia dump file '" + wikipediaDumpFile.getAbsolutePath()
                                + "' does not exist or is not readable, please check the path. ");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }

                    // to calculate indexing time as a performance measure
                    Date start = new Date();

                    try {
                        logger.debug("Indexing to directory '" + this.indexFolder + "'...");

                        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(this.indexFolder));
                        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_42);
                        IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_42, analyzer);

                        if (create) {
                            // Create new index, remove previous index
                            logger.debug("Creating a new index in directory: '" + this.indexFolder + "'...");
                            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
                        } else {
                            // Add new documents to existing index
                            logger.debug("Updating the index in directory: '" + this.indexFolder + "'...");
                            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
                        }

                        // index
                        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
                        indexDocuments(writer, wikipediaDumpFile);
                        writer.close();

                        // time stamping
                        Date end = new Date();
                        logger.debug("Indexing time: " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) + " total milliseconds for " + WikipediaTextFacetIndexer.counter + " articles.");

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.error("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Indexes individual pages from the wikipedia dump with a set of configured IndexFieldGenerators.
                 *
                 * @param writer               A writing handle to the index
                 * @param file                      The file to be indexed
                 * @throws IOException
                 */
                private void indexDocuments(final IndexWriter writer, File file) throws IOException {

                    // reset the file counter
                    WikipediaTextFacetIndexer.counter = 0;

                    // do not try to index files that cannot be read
                    if (file.canRead()) {

                        if (file.isDirectory()) {
                            String[] files = file.list();

                            // an IO error could occur
                            if (files != null) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                                    indexDocuments(writer, new File(file, files[i]));
                                }
                            }

                        } else {

                            FileInputStream fis;
                            try {
                                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                                // at least on windows, some temporary files raise this exception with an "access denied" message
                                // checking if the file can be read doesn't help
                                return;
                            }

                            try {

                                // create a new, empty document
                                final Document doc = new Document();

                                // access wikipedia dump file
                                WikiXMLParser wxsp = WikiXMLParserFactory.getSAXParser(file.getAbsolutePath());

                                try {
                                    wxsp.setPageCallback(new PageCallbackHandler() {
                                        public void process(WikiPage page) {

                                                                                          if (page.isRedirect() || page.isDisambiguationPage() || page.isSpecialPage() || page.isStub()) {
                                                logger.info("- Excluding Redirection / Disambiguation / Special / Stub Wikipedia page id " + page.getID() + " about '"  + page.getTitle().trim() + "'");
                                                return;
                                            }

                                            // facetid is wikipedia ID
                                            // check if docId was read successfully, stop if not
                                            if (page.getID() == null || page.getID().length() == 0) {
                                                logger.error("Facet Id unknown for wikipedia article '" + page.getTitle() + "'. Nothing done.");
                                                return;
                                            }

                                            // id
                                            doc.add(new IntField("id", new Integer(page.getID()), Field.Store.NO));
                                            logger.info("id: " + page.getID());

                                            // title
                                            doc.add(new TextField("title", page.getTitle().trim(), Field.Store.NO));
                                            logger.info("title: " + page.getTitle());

                                            // text
                                            doc.add(new TextField("text", page.getText().trim(), Field.Store.NO));
                                            logger.info("TEXT: " + page.getText());


                                            // original wikipedia text --- excludes some Wiki markup
                                            //doc.add(new TextField("wikitext", page.getWikiText(), Field.Store.YES));

                                            // infobox
                                            InfoBox infoBox = page.getInfoBox();
                                            if (infoBox != null) {
                                                doc.add(new TextField("infobox", page.getInfoBox().dumpRaw(), Field.Store.NO));
                                                logger.info("infobox: " + page.getInfoBox().dumpRaw());
                                            }

                                            // links
                                            Vector links = page.getLinks();
                                            String linksString = "";
                                            for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
                                                linksString = linksString + links.get(i);
                                                if (i < (links.size() - 1)) {
                                                    linksString = linksString + ";";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            doc.add(new TextField("links", linksString.trim(), Field.Store.NO));
                                            logger.info("links: " + linksString.trim());

                                            // categories
                                            Vector categories = page.getCategories();
                                            String categoriesString = "";
                                            for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {
                                                categoriesString = categoriesString + categories.get(i);
                                                if (i < (categories.size() - 1)) {
                                                    categoriesString = categoriesString + ";";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            doc.add(new TextField("categories", categoriesString.trim(), Field.Store.NO));
                                            logger.info("cat: " + categoriesString.trim());


                                            // redirect page
                                            if (page.getRedirectPage() != null){
                                                doc.add(new TextField("redirectPage", page.getRedirectPage(), Field.Store.NO));
                                                logger.info("redirect: " + page.getRedirectPage());
                                            }

                                            // translated titles for French, German and Spanish
                                            if (page.getTranslatedTitle(Language.FRENCH) != null){
                                                doc.add(new TextField("translatedTitleFR", page.getTranslatedTitle(Language.FRENCH), Field.Store.NO));
                                                logger.info("translate: " + page.getTranslatedTitle(Language.FRENCH));
                                            }
                                            if (page.getTranslatedTitle(Language.GERMAN) != null){
                                                doc.add(new TextField("translatedTitleFR", page.getTranslatedTitle(Language.GERMAN), Field.Store.NO));
                                                logger.info("translate: " + page.getTranslatedTitle(Language.GERMAN));
                                            }
                                            if (page.getTranslatedTitle(Language.SPANISH) != null){
                                                doc.add(new TextField("translatedTitleFR", page.getTranslatedTitle(Language.SPANISH), Field.Store.NO));
                                                logger.info("translate: " + page.getTranslatedTitle(Language.SPANISH));
                                            }

                                            // write document to index
                                            try {
                                                logger.debug("[" + WikipediaTextFacetIndexer.counter + "] + Adding Wikipedia page id " + page.getID() + " about '" + page.getTitle().trim() + "'");
                                                writer.addDocument(doc);
                                                WikipediaTextFacetIndexer.counter++;

                                                // just build a small index with 5000 concepts first!!! Remove later !!!
                                                if (WikipediaTextFacetIndexer.counter == 100) {
                                                    writer.commit();
                                                    writer.close();
                                                    System.exit(0);
                                                }

                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                logger.error("Exception while writing index: " + e.getMessage());
                                            }
                                        }

                                    });

                                    wxsp.parse();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            } finally {
                                fis.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return;
                }

            }
```

Comment: What makes you think that the index size will grow linearly with the number of articles?

Comment: Are you removing stopwords?

Comment: Solved. It was about me not clearing already indexed words and keep adding everything on top... so it would have grown infinitive ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have detected one error in your code. When you write the document, you don't remove the fields from the Document, so every time you add a document, it has the fields of the former articles and the new ones, since these haven't been removed. So, when you obtain results, they all seem to be the same, having a huge number of fields (stored fields*number of articles).

To solve it, I added

```
doc.removeField("id");
doc.removeField("title");
doc.removeField("text");
doc.removeField("wikitext");
```

after

```
writer.addDocument(doc);
```

Edit: just finished a complete index from the 8 GB spanish dump, with only the id, title(stored), wikitext(stored) and infobox fields. Only 4,8GB

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of feasible explanations this.  You raised one yourself, you could have just gotten some larger articles to start with.  Did you check if that was the case?  If not, why not?  You certainly can't assume uniform data when dealing with wikipedia content.

Also, aside from any size costs with just starting a new index, lucene is an inverted index.  New terms indexed will take up more space than a term the index has seen before.  It's reasonable to assume that, as you move through documents, they will tend to take less space as you go, since most of their terms already exist in the index by that time.